# Cookie manager PHP

Tags: php, joomla, cookie, affiliate

I own a Joomla commerce store and although I use Google Analytics in order to track visitors, I need to install a cookie manager in order to be able to track cookies that were installed on customer when he punctuate an order.

To be more specific , I am planning to join an affiliate network and I need somehow to track no only the last visit of a customer but if he has a cookie and from which affiliate network as well.

Answer (score 2):

There are many components within the Joomla extension libaary which should be able to help, here is a couple as an example:

- [WizAffiliates](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/ads-a-affiliates/affiliate-systems/affiliate-advertising/17660)
- [VM Affiliate - Requires Virtuemark](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension-specific/virtuemart-extensions/virtuemart-ads/4487)

For even more check out [Joomla extensions library for Affiliates](http://extensions.joomla.org/search?q=affiliate)

If you can't find something suitable then sadly your need to make your own or have someone do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

I didnt install another 3rd party component in order to avoid extra "weight" on existing site, what i did was to create a few php lines in the head of the template where i was checking if current page had a parameter in the url similar to affiliate network has when drivers visitors from their network to my site. If page was same i was created a cookie with same life-time as affiliates. 
Finally on every order that is punctuated in the site, i am checking my cookie is exists on that customer, if so that user should be from affiliate.

Its not ideal but its worked for me & i avoided any 3rd party component.